# Can't assign to comparison in a simple command

Tags: python

I started some really simple coding watching a simple tutorial. When I tried to run this command, I've been getting this error:

`Can't assign to comparison`

I searched this error but found it on a more advanced code that I do not understand.

Can someone please explain?

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits: x in fruits[0] = "apple"
print(x)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish doing the assignment. Please [edit] your question and explain what you're trying to accomplish with the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is complaining because keyword 'in' was used in wrong place.

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
   fruits[0] = "apple"
print(x)
```

This works. Although loop doesn't do something meaningful.

example usage of in:

```
if 'a' in 'abc':
    print('yay')

for x in (1, 2, 3):
    # x become 1, 2, 3 each loop, this is called iteration.
    print(x)
```